# Google Analytics Missing Some Event Actions (Recorded in Real Time but not in Behavior)

Tags: google-analytics

I am using the Google Analytics Measurement Protocol to send events, there is one category and several actions. There are currently a couple dozen GA Accounts that I am sending data to (successfully) but there's one that's experiencing very bizarre behavior.

Only one action is ever being logged for this account under Behavior -> Events, but the other two (missing) actions are shown under real time. The account is using UA and the session timeout is set to 30 minutes. The first action is typically sent several minutes before the next actions.

I can verify that the requests for other actions are being sent with 200-responses. There also appears to be no filter for the missing actions or anything else that would prevent them from showing.

There is a conversion involving the missing actions and when attempting to do a verify I do get a non-zero conversion rate.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Edit: The data collection has been running for a month.

Comment: I've had an issue in the past were a null or '' string/value doesn't show up in reports. Can you post the JS or verify the values that are sent to GA? Can you also send a pageview to help debug where the URL is /event/[mycat]/[myaction]/[mylabel]/

Comment: @osowskit I am not using any JS nor is there a page, this is using the GA Measurement Protocol because I need to track events that may occur after the visitor leaves the page.

Comment: Right. Can you post the URL for the event that works and one that doesn't so I can test this?